# Change permission on a string of directories

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a string of directories and i want to change the permission on all of these directories to 775 (rwxrwxr-x) with a command like chmod.

The problem is that the string is editable so it can be different from user to user, so chmod -R doesn't work because one user may have

```
/apple/a/b
```

while another user has

```
/android/a/b/c/d
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Is there a criteria to enumerate these directories since they will be different for all users? If you can enumerate them with a find command, it would be pretty easy to do. If the change is random and there is no way of listing them all programatically, you'd have to do it on a per user basis using terdon's suggestions. Also, please note if this should be affecting just the folder or all the files inside as well.

Comment: Is there something that you know? I mean that is the same for all users? Does `a/b/c` also change? Please give us an actual example and specify which parts of the string are always the same.

Comment: yes a/b/c changes as well.

Comment: So, if the string is `/a/b/c/d`, you want to change the permissions of `/a`, `/a/b`, `/a/b/c` and `/a/b/c/d`?

Comment: Yes but the string can have more or less directories and with different names.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to be able to change the permissions of an arbitrary set of directories (without affecting their files) automatically? How would the hypothetical command know which directories to change? Will you be giving a different string each time? Please post a few specific examples so we can understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If the variable *string* contains the path `/a/b/c/d`, the following instructions will change the permissions of `/a`, `/a/b`, `/a/b/c` and `/a/b/c/d`:

```
(
    IFS=/
    unset substring

    for dir in $string; do
        unset IFS
        substring="$substring$dir/"
        test "$substring" != "/" && chmod 755 "$substring"
    done
)
```

#### How it works

- The parentheses execute everything in a subshell, so changing the variables *IFS* and *substring* won't have any effect outside the subshell.
- `IFS=/` sets the internal file separator to *slash*, so the for loop will split `$string` at the slashes.
- `for dir in $string; do ... done` will execute `...` once for every component in `$string`.

  In our example, `$dir` will take the values , `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.
- `unset IFS` changes the internal file separator back to default, since it will affect slashes in the directory paths.
- `substring="$substring$dir/"` appends the current value of `$dir` to `$substring`.

  In our example, `$susbtring` will take the values `/`, `/a/`, `/a/b/`, `/a/b/c/` and `/a/b/c/d/`.
- `test "$substring" != "/" && chmod 755 "$substring"` checks if the current value of `$susbtring` is different from `/`.

  If it is, it sets the desired permissions.

Comment: Very nice, +1. Especially for using quotes so it works with dir names that have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Are these directories subdirectories of each other? Anyway, here are some choices:

1. Change permissions on dir1 and **all** its subdirectories and files

   ```
   chmod -R 775 dir1
   ```
2. Change permissions on dir1 and specific subdirectories

   ```
   chmod  775 dir1 dir1/dir2 /dir1/dir2/dir3
   ```
3. Change permissions on all subdirectories of dir1

   ```
   find dir1 -type d -exec chmod 775 {}\;
   ```

Comment: I think your `chmod -R` would change perms on files too? I think `find -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;' or equiv is what you want.

Comment: that doesn't work because you would have to know the first directory and that could be anything.

Comment: Why _don't_ you know the first directory? Why do you need to make a very generic thing? What's the use case?